# Question about affine coordinate changes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Fulton in [his book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) defines affine coordinate changes:

[image]

I'm trying to prove the item (b) of this question:

[image]

Let's prove using the induction suggestion.

Suppose $V=V(F_1)$, where $F_1=b_1X_1+\ldots+b_nX_n+b_0$, then $V^T=V(F_1^T)=V(F\circ T)$. I've found this change of coordinates:

$$T'=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        b_1^{-1} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
        0        & 0 &    \ldots   & 0  \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$ and

$$T''=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -b_1^{-1}b_0 \\
        0 \\
        \vdots  \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

So, $F_1^T=X_1$ and $V^T=V(X_1)$, the problem is $T'$ I've found is not invertible, is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the OP noticed in his comments, the other answer to this question is incorrect.

Let $F(X) = a_1X_1 + a_2X_2+\dots+a_nX_n + b$.
WLOG, suppose that $a_1\neq 0$.
Then define $T = (T_1,\dots,T_n)$ by
\begin{align*}
T_1(X) &= \frac{1}{a_1}X_1 -\frac{a_2}{a_1}X_2-\cdots-\frac{a_n}{a_1}X_n - \frac{b}{a_1},
\\\\
T_i(X) &= X_i, \text{ if }i\geq 2.
\end{align*}

Then you can check that
$
(F\circ T)(X) = X_1,
$
thus $V^T = V(X_1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is linear and defined by a single polynomial equation $a_1x_1+\ldots+a_nx_n=0$, then put $x_1' = a_1x_1+\ldots+a_nx_n$.

Then consider the map $\mathbb A^n \to \mathbb A^n$ given by $x_1 \mapsto x_1'$ and $x_i \mapsto x_i$. This is obviously an isomorphism as long as $a_1 \neq 0$.

In the image of this map, $V$ is defined by $x_1'=0$.

Comment: I didn't understand, so according to your definition $T_1(X)=a_1X_1+\ldots+a_nX_n, T_2(X)=X_2,\ldots,T_n(X)=X_n$, is that right?

Comment: @user42912 Yes, correct.

Comment: By definition we have $V^T=V(F_1^T)=V(F_1\circ T)$, where $F_1=a_1x_1+\ldots+a_nx^n$. So I didn't understand why in your example: $V^T=V(X_1)$. According to my calculations we have $V^T=V(F^T)$, where $F^T=a_1^2X_1+(a_1+1)(a_2X_1+\ldots+a_nX_n)$.